Friction between the two blocks

In a given problem, a force is applied to a block which sits on top of another block which in turns sits on a table top. The coefficients of friction between the lower block and the table is given as $\mu_1$ and the coefficient between the upper block and the lower block is given as $\mu_2$, and are coefficients of limiting and kinetic friction.


I am not interested in the numerical solution, as this is already given: (The solutions are the blocks are moving together with acceleration $(31/9) \,\text{m}/\,\text{s}^2$ and the friction between blocks is $26.22\,\text{N}$).
What I want to understand is why the two blocks move together, instead of sliding relative to each other and why the friction between the two blocks is not just the total force minus the force used to accelerate the top block?

What exactly is the problem statement?

The original question in the book is asking to find the friction between the blocks and the accelerations of the blocks.

@AkhileshG I have added a paragraph to my answer, to clarify why the blocks move together as a result of following the path of least resistance. Let me know if it makes sense to you now.

You can safely assume the coefficients of friction are for sliding friction. If you work out the force required for the top block to slide relative to the lower block, it is much greater than the force required to slide both blocks relative to the table top, so the path of least resistance is for both the blocks to slide as a single unit relative to the table top and the top block does not move relative to the lower block.
I will use notation such that quantities with subscripts of 1 or or 2 apply to the lower and top blocks respectively and no subscript applies to both blocks as a single unit. The sliding friction force between the combined block and the table top is $f = \mu_1 \ m \ g = 0.1 \times 9 *10 = 9 \ N$. The net force accelerating the pair of blocks is F = 40-9 = 31 N. The acceleration of the pair is $a = F/m = 31/9 = 3.444\ m/s^2$.
The force required to accelerate the lower block to 3.444 $m/s^2$ is $F_1 = m_1 \ a = 5 \times 3.444 = 17.222$ N. The friction between the upper block and lower block has to provide this force and an additional force of 9 N to overcome the sliding friction between the lower block and the table, so the inter-block friction has to be $17.222 + 9 = 26.222$ N.
Subtract the above figure from 40N and the result is 13.777 N and that is the force required to accelerate the top block on its own to 3.444 $m/s^2$.
Edit: With hindsight, there is a simpler way I could have done the calculation. First calculate the joint acceleration of the two blocks (answer $3.444 \ m/s^2$). Next, calculate the force required to accelerate the top block on its own to $3.444 \ m/s^2$ (answer $F_1 = m_2 a = 3.444 \times 4 = 13.777 $ N). What is left (40 - 13.777 = 26.222 N) must be the force transmitted to the lower block from the top block, via the inter-block static friction force.
Note that the sliding friction coefficient $\mu_2 = 0.9$ is not required to calculate the inter-block friction because there is no relative motion between the top and lower blocks. The static friction matches whatever force is being applied by the top block on the lower block. If a coefficient of static friction is quoted, it is only an indication of the maximum friction that can be applied before static friction is no longer relevant and the actual inter-block static friction is a variable that matches whatever force is applied, up until the maximum.
ADDENDUM:
Let me elaborate on the path of least resistance, as it is key to why the blocks move together. First, imagine only the top block moves. The dynamic friction between the blocks would be $f_{21} = \mu_2 \ m_2\ g = 0.8 \times 4 \times 10 = 32 $ N. This inter-block friction accelerates the lower block and the acceleration of the lower block works out as $(32 - 0.1\times 9 \times 10)/5 = 4.6 \ m/s^2$. The acceleration of the top block works out as $(40-32)/4 = 2 m/s^2$. Since the lower block is accelerating at a greater rate than the upper block, the lower block catches up with the upper block and there relative motion goes to zero. Now there is no relative motion between the blocks and since static friction is greater than dynamic friction the blocks are effectively locked together and move as one.

Well explained. Thank you!

The problem has not been clear on whether or not you're dealing with static friction or kinetic friction. However, if they do slide together, then the friction between the blocks is static friction, and the most common error introductory students make is that static friction $f_s=\mu_sN$. This is only true if slipping is just about to occur between the two blocks; however, in this case we aren't told that is happening, so we can't assume equality. All we know is that $f_s\leq\mu_sN$
To find the friction between the two blocks, you first find the acceleration of the blocks together (don't overthink this part), then use Newton's second law on just the top block to determine the friction force acting on it in order for it to have that acceleration.


Why are the blocks moving together?

Assuming both coefficients are for static friction, then it’s because the maximum possible static friction force between the lower block and the surface (9N) is less than the maximum possible static friction force between the blocks (32N), meaning impending motion of the combined blocks will occur first, with an acceleration based on applying Newton’s second law to the combined blocks.

And why is the friction between the blocks not 32 N, but 26.22N?

Because 32N is the maximum possible static friction force, which would only be reached when motion between the blocks is impending. Since they both move together the actual static friction force is less than the maximum possible static friction force. It is the friction force that the lower block exerts on the upper block. That is determined by applying Newton’s second law to the upper block alone, given its acceleration is the same as the combined blocks.
I would add that, based on their solution, it appears they are using 0.1 for both static and kinetic friction. Normally, kinetic is less.
Hope this helps.
